# How to fix UITableView cell repeat in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I create a new cell it will automatically mark
or when I marked the first one, I was creating multiple
Cell, there will be duplicates marked

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let itemCellIdentifier = "itemCell"

    guard let  itemCell = itemCardTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ItemCardTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let itemCard = dataManager.items[indexPath.row]
    itemCell.itemTitle.text = itemCard.title

    if itemCard.isFinish {
        itemCell.itemCellView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 123, blue: 0)
    }
    return itemCell
}
```

Add cell method

```
let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "確認", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

        guard let title = addAlert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }

        let newItem = ItemCard(title: title, isFinish: false)
        self.dataManager.items.append(newItem)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.itemCardTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: 0)
        self.itemCardTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
```

When I create new data isFinish = false

How can I fix data duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide else case to set default background color.

```
if itemCard.isFinish {
    itemCell.itemCellView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 123, blue: 0)
} else {
    itemCell.itemCellView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, You should hold the `isFinish` flag somewhere out of the cell, because it's being reused by tableView.

You can create the `finished = [Bool]()` is your UIViewController and every time check `finished[indexPath.row]` to see if it's marked or not and pass the boolean to your cell.